# Flask - Pass back response of inner request

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I looked at some of the similar suggested SO questions, but they weren't quite what I was looking for:

I have a Flask server with a POST route that calls another server. I want Flask to return the response from that request as-is.

```
import os
import requests
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, make_response, Response

@app.route('/stuff', methods=['POST'])
def get_stuff():
    resp = requests.post(...)
    return resp

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=9999)
```

I've tried the following but each returns an error:

```
return jsonify(resp)
return ( resp.raw.read(), resp.status_code, resp.headers.items() )
return Response(json.dumps(resp), status=resp.status_code, mimetype='application/json')
```

I just want it to pass back what it got

Answer (score 1):

Flask route functions should only return a string, you need a method to convert it and each of the attempts you made probably fell short in one way or another to do so.

Post the error messages, they may clue in how close you are to accomplishing the rerouting of the post response.